# How to use obtained credentials in powershell to find groups of the Authenticated user?

Tags: powershell, authentication, active-directory, credentials, active-directory-group

I wrote a script, which on execution asks for credentials; it goes like this;

```
$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
$CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI] "" ).distinguishedName
$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,    $UserName, $Password)

if ($domain.name -eq $null)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication failed - please verify your username and password.")
    exit
}
else
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication Success")

    $Groups = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups
```

-> I recognized my mistake later, the last line collects the groups of user who is logged into the windows machine.I need the groups of the person who authenticated via script; how to change this and obtain the groups for the person who authenticated into script rather the one using windows authentication?

Please do let me know of any questions or clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")$cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
$username = $cred.username
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
$CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI] "" ).distinguishedName
$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,    $UserName, $Password)

if ($domain.name -eq $null)
{
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
  [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication failed - please verify your username and password.")
  exit
}
else
{
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

  $cred = Get-Credential #Read credentials
  $username = $cred.username
  $password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
  $CurrentDomain = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI] "" ).distinguishedName
  $domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($CurrentDomain,    $UserName, $Password)

  if ($domain.name -eq $null)
  {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication failed - please verify your username and password.")
    exit
  }
  else
  {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Authentication Success")

    $ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
    $user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($ct, $username)

    $groups = $user.GetGroups()
    foreach($i in $groups){
      $i.SamAccountName
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This line "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" is it available in all powershell installations? because we are introducing the script in arestrictive environment, is this a builtin module on does it need any addons?

Comment: it's a .net namespace, framework 3.5 ... IIRC, try also  `[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")`

Comment: we are going as low as .net 2.0(which is min requirement for powershell 2.0) in our implementation , currectly i tested ur block it works perfectlt, but my only concern is to make it universal without depending on any libraries.Let me know your thoughts , i am selecting ur response as the answer, thank you.

Comment: Currecntly the below code worked for me well;                     $filter = "(&(objectCategory=$category)(SamAccountname=$user))"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry 
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $filter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$objSearcher.FindOne()
$Groups = $Obj.Propertied"memberof"

Comment: @Darktux Yes, I was just writing you to use [ADSI] and read about it here: http://www.blackops.ca/cms/blog/?p=251, Accountmanagement namespace is't a little more short, but maybe some computer have just .net 2.0..

Answer (score 0):

if you're able to install [quest activesrole](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) it will be as simple as :

```
(get-qaduser $user).memberof
```

otherwise you can use invoke-command and provide the credentials:

```
$groups=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups
}
```

Comment: This goes on lot of workstations, cant install quest roles on all of them.

Comment: It gives an error about WINRM , executing this "[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups
" alone works but this whole script fails; why do we need to involve a "-computername" since i just want groups for the authenticated user?

Comment: the parametersets of invoke-command forces us to use -computername if we want to use -credential... i don't understand your reply, what is failing ? could you provide the complete error msg and update you question to see your updated script and how do you run it on the workstations ?